# How to move framed paintings by plane

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage, tsa

I will soon move with two paintings by air. I'm afraid to check them to avoid damage.

Last time I was able to bring them as carry-on and give it to the FA for the coat hanger. She did so grudgingly, therefore I have the feeling I should be better prepared this time, hence the question.

Specific info:

- Size: ~50x80 cm or 20x30"
- Material: Nothings hazardous, no glass
- Packaged: Bubble wrap & card bord box
- Route: SFO -> ZRH

Comment: Have you considered shipping then? There are companies that specialize in this. When I had to move framed artwork between BWI and DEN, and from Detroit to DEN, I used a shipping company.

Comment: As alternative pack them in a solid, tough box, preferably one designed for this, and check them.

Comment: @Roddy this is the plan B. I would prefer them going with me though because of their sentimental value to me

Comment: The dimensions of your frame exceed the maximum size of hand baggage allowed on Swiss (55 x 40 x 23 cm). Many airlines have special rules for large fragile objects (mostly large music instruments), sometimes requiring a seat to be booked for those, but I don’t see anything relevant on the Swiss site, and I’m not sure how it would work in your case (difficult to strap the painting to a seat...). You may want to call Swiss.

Comment: if you're flying business, you'll get more leeway, but crated and treated as outsize-baggage will mean you can have them in the hold but use a LOT of bubblewrap.  Alternatively remove them from the frames and roll them up (assuming not painted directly on a board).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to move framed paintings is this:

1. Get a local specialist to remove the painting from the frame and to tear the frame apart.
2. Have it transported in a cylinder, the specialist might provide one.
3. Once at the destination have a local specialist assembly the frame and painting.

I've seen this done many times, always with perfect result.